# Create new template in Discussion Forum theme

Tags: forum

I am working on customizing the theme of EE Discussion Forum and some of pages need to add/remove sections. For which I would like to create new template and include within appropriate template like `{include:html_header}`.

But when I am including the new created template, getting the error message like "Page not available".

Can anyone please suggest me if its possible. If possible, how can I achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can add new templates without hacking the core forum .php files, I did try this a while back. My solution was to utilise existing templates and reposition them as necessary.

Comment: @Bluedreamer Thanks for your input. Yes, you are right. I did the same by utilizing the exiting templates.

Answer (score 1):

Several years ago, the EllisLab staff posted something about having a replacement for the hilariously outdated forum package that EE ships with. Then EE4 came out.... then EE5 came out.... then EllisLab was acquired.... and we've not heard of it since. I suspect it is dead, and never to see the light of day. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom templates in Discussion forum by customizing the core files of plugin. But it becomes very lengthy process.